# Problem with thesis class

Tags: errors, thesis

When I am trying to use the `thesis` class file for my thesis I am getting this error:

```
File `thesis.cls' not found. \usepackage
```

**My codes**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{thesis}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\chapter{How long you want the title }

\end{document}
```

How to correct this error?

Comment: have you put thesis.cls file in the same folder as your .tex?

Comment: that would be `thesis.cls` not `.sty` there are dozens if not hundreds of _different_ classes called `thesis.cls` from every university department ever. presumably you had some documentation that said to use some particular local class and that documentation should have said where it could be found

Comment: Try `Thesis`. If that works, replace `Thesis` by `book`.

Comment: Otherwise just start your document using `\documentclass{report}` until you get any local instructions that mandate the use of a particular class.

Answer (score 4):

### If you have access to `thesis.cls`:

Most of the time an error `File foo.cls not found` leads to two possible problems:

First, the `cls` file is a "classic" file that is part of TeXlive or other TeX distribution. In this case, you should update it. The way to do it depends if you are using TeXlive, MikTeX, macTeX or other system.

If your file comes from internet, or from another source as an University, you should have a copy of the file in your folder.

If the problem is still present, you should verify typo (`thesis`, `Thesis` or `THESIS`). The name depends on the file name.

### If you don't have any `thesis.cls` file:

In this case you should use another document class as `book` or `report`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} %you can modifies report with book
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\chapter{How long you want the title }

\end{document}
```

Comment: How to fix this in linux..means i am using texstudio as an editor..

Comment: @David have you the thesis.cls file? If it's the case, just put it in the same folder as your tex document and voilà `;-)`

Comment: no i am not having

Comment: @David then do not use `\documentclass{thesis}` use `\documentclass{report}` and it will work.

Comment: @David I've modified my answer. The comment by David Carlisle is what you have to do